# Iterating through images using forward and back buttons

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, loops

I have five images that I want to iterate through as a gallery. So when a user clicks a "forward button" the next image in an array displays in a div. And also when "back button" is clicked. Sorry if this is stupid coding but I am very new here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // when thumbnail is clicked

    $("img#thumb").click(function () {
        var imgpath = $(this).attr("src");
        $("img#cover").attr("src", imgpath);

    });

    $(function () {
        $("img#thumb").bind('click', function () {
            var img = $(this).clone(); //this clones the img, so you do not need to re-load that using src path
            $("img#cover").hide().html(img).fadeIn(500); //remove .hide() segment if you just are hiding by css rules

        });
    });

    //when the nextimage link is clicked
    var imgs = ["images/exteriors/abandonned/img0.jpg",
                "images/exteriors/abandonned/img1.jpg",
                "images/exteriors/abandonned/img2.jpg"];

    $("img#nextimage").click(function () {

        $.each(imgs, function () {

            $("img#cover").attr("src", imgs); // I want to iterate each image and display when it is clicked
        });

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbs"> <!--gallery thumbs-->
<img id="thumb1" src="images/exteriors/abandonned/img0.jpg" width="100px" height="80px" class="" /><br>
<img id="thumb2" src="images/exteriors/abandonned/img1.jpg" width="100px" height="80px" class="" /><br>
<img id="thumb3" src="images/exteriors/abandonned/img2.jpg" width="100px" height="80px" class="" /><br>
 <img id="thumb" src="images/exteriors/abandonned/img3.jpg" width="100px" height="80px" class="" /><br>
 <img id="thumb" src="images/exteriors/abandonned/img3.jpg" width="100px" height="80px" class="" /><br>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate the images on each click of the next or previous button; instead, use a variable to store an index into the imgs array, and have your click handler update that index and then update the  tag's src attribute with the URL at that index in the array. Something like this, perhaps:

```
var imgindex = 0;

$('img#nextimage').click(function() {
  imgindex++; // increment the index into array 'imgs'
  if (imgindex > (imgs.length - 1)) { imgindex = 0; }; // if we just walked off the far end of the array, reset the index to zero (loop around to the 1st image)
  $('img#cover').attr('src', imgs[imgindex]); // update the img src
});

$('img#previmage').click(function() {
  imgindex--; // decrement the array index
  if (imgindex < 0) { imgindex = (images.length - 1); }; // if we just walked off the near end of the array, loop around to the last image
  $('img#cover').attr('src', imgs[imgindex]);
});
```

Comment: I notice you have a condition that the loop resets if index is larger than the length of the array. How do I know ho long my array is? Is that the length of characters in the values?

Comment: I did what you said and it worked somewhat. The image switches but it doesn't "stick" it flips back to the previous one! It kind of just flashes.

Comment: I'm getting the length of the array by its length property -- 'imgs.length' in the above example. That property exists on all JS array objects, and contains a number indicating how many elements are in the array -- since the array's indexed from zero, subtracting 1 from the length property gives the index of the last element. Regarding the change not sticking -- I'd guess that has to do with one of the other event handlers. I'd suggest starting with just the imgs array from your code, and then my answer, and build from there -- I can't tell what might be wrong from what I'm looking at here.

Comment: ok thanks a lot! The advice you gave is more than helpful and I will post any updates as I go. edit: I think I know the problem, when the next image link is clicked the page refreshes thereby meaning imgsindex is reset to 0 and the same image flashes again.